# Why can I not import a list of emails into a mailing list? SOLVED

Tags: mailinglist

I am trying to batch import a list of emails and I get the error:
The following emails could not be imported:
then a long list of all my emails.

What stops EE from importing these emails?  They all appear to be correct.

Strange thing is emails can be batch entered individually but not as a batch.

Emails that failed to import in a batch can be imported individually

I think there were some hidden tabs or something. Finally got it to work

Comment: Next time, don't edit your question to include the answer. Use the answer form to post the answer yourself, then mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there were some hidden tabs or something. Finally got it to work